# Disable tex-mode's auto tex-insert-quote functionaliy

Tags: key-bindings, latex, tex-mode

So basically, for reasons unknown we don't use regular LaTeX style quotes at my company, instead just using regular double quotes. However, tex-mode in emacs automatically substitutes the `"` key for ``` ``'' ```. I can't find any way of disabling this.

I've tried setting `tex-open-quote` and `tex-close-quote` to `"`, which works to some degree, but when inserting quotes inside a `\verb!!`, it still substitutes the first `!` with `` `'' `` for some unknown reason.

I'm using Doom-Emacs, but I doubt this has anything to do with the functionality.

Is there any way of completely disabling this functionality, or at least unmapping the `"` key from `tex-insert-quote`?

Comment: Have you tried disabling it in pure Emacs without init file? (`emacs -q`)

Comment: Typing " twice should result in a classical ".

Comment: Firstly, that doesn't really solve my problem, as I don't want to have to double tap quotes every time. Secondly, that doesn't even work in my emacs. There's likely something broken in either my config or in doom-emacs itself.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you using AUC-Tex?

Comment: I don't believe so. I haven't installed anything additional, I'm just using the defaults from doom-emacs. `C-h m` says my major mode is `tex-mode` and I don't spot any other tex-related minor modes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be smartparens doing (another package that Doom uses). Even if you unmap the double quote key like so:

```
(map! :after tex
      :map TeX-mode-map
      "\"" nil)

;; this is equivalent to
(with-eval-after-load 'tex
  (define-key TeX-mode-map "\"" nil))
```

Smartparens' defaults will still kick in when you type a double quote. You can disable this troublesome rule with:

```
(after! smartparens-latex
  (sp-local-pair '(tex-mode plain-tex-mode latex-mode LaTeX-mode)
                  "``" "''" :actions :rem))

;; This is equivalent to
(with-eval-after-load 'smartparens-latex
  (sp-local-pair '(tex-mode plain-tex-mode latex-mode LaTeX-mode)
                  "``" "''" :actions :rem))
```

I'll look into merging this into the lang/latex module upstream.

Comment: Thanks, this got me on the right track, although the maps that you suggested don't quite work. I've tweaked a bit and gotten it working. My working fix in the related github issue: https://github.com/hlissner/doom-emacs/issues/1688 If you fix your solution, I'll accept your answer as it narrowed down the true culprit.

Comment: In vanilla emacs, it was neccessary for me to use both `(setq TeX-quote-after-quote t)` and `(with-eval-after-load 'smartparens-latex
  (sp-local-pair '(tex-mode plain-tex-mode latex-mode LaTeX-mode)
                  "``" "''" :actions :rem))` 
to get desired behaviour -- which is being able to insert double quotes as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can rebind the `"` key in `tex-mode` with the following:

```lisp
(eval-after-load "tex-mode"
  (define-key tex-mode-map "\"" 'self-insert-command))
```

`self-insert-command` turns `"` back into a normal key, it will just insert itself when you press it. If you want it to do anything else, use a different function here.

Comment: No luck. For some reason your binding command did not work, although I was able to get the binding to work using some doom-emacs helper macros. Either way, it still inserts the latex funky quotes. I've done `C-h "` while in insert mode and can confirm it has indeed mapped correctly to `self-insert-command`, yet it still replaces the quotes.

Comment: Hmm... I've just tried your remap with `emacs -q` as suggested by @DoMiNeLa10 and it does work correctly. It seems doom-emacs must be interfering somehow. Will consult on the doom-emacs github.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using AUCTex, you can use

```lisp
(setq TeX-quote-after-quote t)
```

From the manual: If TeX-quote-after-quote is non-nil, typing " will insert a literal double quote.

Comment: Yeah I don't have AUC-Tex installed so it's definitely not that...

Comment: @ryan27968: I recommend you try out AUCTex. It is really good.